# Which body of the Russian Federation is investigating the Nord Stream sabotage?

Tags: russian-federation, nord-stream, investigation

It's been mentioned a number of times in the Western press, quoting or paraphrasing brief snippets from Russian officials [that](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/kremlin-says-focus-nord-stream-probe-is-now-germany-after-sweden-drops-out-2024-02-07/) Russia is conducting its own probe/investigation into the Nord Stream sabotage.

Which body of the Russian Federation is in charge of this investigation, more precisely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["28 сентября (2022) Генпрокуратура России инициировала дело об акте международного терроризма (ч. 1 ст. 361 Уголовного кодекса РФ)..."](https://tass.ru/info/17258101#:%7E:text=28%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%20(%D1%87.%201%20%D1%81%D1%82.%20361%20%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%A4).)

> On September 28, the Prosecutor General's Office of Russia initiated a case on an act of international terrorism (Part 1 of Article 361 of the Criminal Code of the Russian Federation).

So, it is the [Prosecutor General's Office](https://epp.genproc.gov.ru/web/gprf/about-the-proc), like in Germany ([Generalbundesanwalt leitet wegen »Nord Stream«-Sabotage Ermittlungsverfahren ein](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/sabotage-angriff-auf-nord-stream-pipelines-generalbundesanwalt-leitet-ermittlungsverfahren-ein-a-8c31ce46-23ca-4a88-85db-667eb8e153a2)), Denmark and others.

Also here: ["В декабре 2023 г. был получен отказ Генеральной прокуратуры Дании в ответ на обращение Генеральной прокуратуры Российской Федерации о правовой помощи в расследовании диверсий на газопроводах «Северный поток – 1» и «Северный поток – 2»."](https://www.mid.ru/ru/foreign_policy/news/1927060/)

> Copenhagen and Stockholm continue to refuse any interaction with the Russian side on this issue. In December 2023, a refusal was received from the Danish Prosecutor General's Office in response to an appeal from the Russian Prosecutor General's Office for legal assistance in the investigation of sabotage on the Nord Stream 1 and Nord Stream 2 gas pipelines.

Comment: I'm not sure how the "Also here" link is relevant. It's only about the Danes, AFAICT. (I'll award the bounty, but I need to wait 5 hours or so before the system lets me do that.)

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat the official investigation request was sended from  Prosecutor General's Office of RF to same department of Danes

Comment: I see. I've added a machine translation.